# How to deserialize the response from an API when the type may differ?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

In my React application, I display a search result on the screen.
I make an API call that will return a different shape depending on the type of user like:

- anonymous
- member
- admin

My shape I mean more or less columns, so I have types defined already like:

```
export interface AnonymousSearchResults {

}

export interface MemberSearchResults extends AnonymousSearchResults {
}
export interface AdminSearchResults ... {
}
```

I then have a union type like:

```
export type SearchResults = AnonymousSearchResults | MemberSearchResults | AdminSearchResults;
```

So when I make an API call, the JSON response will match one of the above types.

What options do I have to deserialize my JSON response to my typescript type?

Comment: I do not understand what you're asking.  The deserialization will give you an object based on what was sent.  It does not respect your types.  If you're asking "how do I determine the type I got back" you have to do some kind of check yourself.

Comment: TS does not and can not automatically detect what the type of something is in the runtime since TS types don't exist in the runtime -- it's compiled out and runs as JS. That means you need to type narrow it yourself using something like Union Discriminators (google that term) or type guard functions. This can be confusing to java/c# devs etc at first which are nominally typed. Your first thought will be "this is incredibly time consuming". And that's where TS type gen tools come in. Like graphql-code-generator for gql, or openapi-generator/swagger-generator for REST (amongst many others).